# Необходимо исправить фильтрацию массива данных

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, filter

С Redis поступает массив данных (категория - value и подкатегория - label) а на клиенте юзер по первым буквам ищет нужную подкатегорию и вместе с ней должна быть категория
пример:
[image: screen]

но как видно на скрине при вводе int подбираются подкатегории (но у первой уже отсутствует категория)
Код:

```js
function course_curriculum_source() {
  var current_curriculum = $('.course-curriculum').data('taggle').getTags().values;
  <% if cache_course_curriculum_tags && cache_curriculum_subcategories_hash %>
  var curriculum_tree = <%= cache_course_curriculum_tags.map { |s| [{label: s, value: 'subject'}, {label: s, value: s}, (cache_curriculum_subcategories_hash[s] || []).map {|ss| {label: ss, value: ss} } ] }.flatten.to_json.html_safe %>;
  curriculum_tree = _.filter(curriculum_tree, function(val) {
    return val.value == 'subject' || current_curriculum.indexOf(val.label) == -1
  });
  $($('.course-curriculum').data('taggle').getInput()).autocomplete('option', 'source', curriculum_tree)
  <% end %>
}
course_curriculum_source();
```

```html
<div class="course-curriculum tags-list">
  <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-378" tabindex="-1">Apologia</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-379" tabindex="-1">Apologia</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-380" tabindex="-1">Exploring Creation with Biology</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-381" tabindex="-1">Exploring Creation with Physical Science</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-382" tabindex="-1">General Science</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-383" tabindex="-1">Beautiful Feet</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-384" tabindex="-1">Beautiful Feet</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-385" tabindex="-1">Canon Press</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-386" tabindex="-1">Canon Press</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-387" tabindex="-1">Introductory Logic - The Fundamentals of Thinking Well</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-388" tabindex="-1">Classical Academic Press</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-389" tabindex="-1">Classical Academic Press</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-390" tabindex="-1">The Art of Argument</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-391" tabindex="-1">Classical Conversations</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-392" tabindex="-1">Classical Conversations</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-393" tabindex="-1">Challenge 1</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-394" tabindex="-1">Challenge 2</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-395" tabindex="-1">Challenge 3</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-396" tabindex="-1">Challenge 4</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-397" tabindex="-1">Challenge A</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-398" tabindex="-1">Challenge B</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-399" tabindex="-1">Essentials</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-400" tabindex="-1">Foundations</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-401" tabindex="-1">Dr. Jay Wile</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-402" tabindex="-1">Dr. Jay Wile</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-403" tabindex="-1">Discovering Design with Chemistry</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-404" tabindex="-1">Henle Latin</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-405" tabindex="-1">Henle Latin</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-406" tabindex="-1">Latin 1</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-407" tabindex="-1">Latin 2</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-408" tabindex="-1">IEW</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-409" tabindex="-1">IEW</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-410" tabindex="-1">Following Narnia® Volume 2: Aslan's Country</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-411" tabindex="-1">Medieval History</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-412" tabindex="-1">Intermediate Logic</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-413" tabindex="-1">Intermediate Logic</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-414" tabindex="-1">Introductory Logic</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-415" tabindex="-1">Introductory Logic</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-416" tabindex="-1">Logic of English</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-417" tabindex="-1">Logic of English</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-418" tabindex="-1">Logic of English C</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-419" tabindex="-1">Lost Tools of Writing</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-420" tabindex="-1">Lost Tools of Writing</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-421" tabindex="-1">Math U See</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-422" tabindex="-1">Math U See</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-423" tabindex="-1">AIM</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-424" tabindex="-1">Math U See Alpha</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-425" tabindex="-1">Math U See Beta</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-426" tabindex="-1">Math U See Geometry</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-427" tabindex="-1">Math U See Pre-Algebra</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-428" tabindex="-1">Math U See: Zeta</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-429" tabindex="-1">Math U See Algebra 2</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-430" tabindex="-1">Memoria Press</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-431" tabindex="-1">Memoria Press</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-432" tabindex="-1">Notgrass</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-433" tabindex="-1">Notgrass</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-434" tabindex="-1">Notgrass Exploring Government</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-435" tabindex="-1">Saxon Math</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-436" tabindex="-1">Saxon Math</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-437" tabindex="-1">Saxon Advanced Math</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-438" tabindex="-1">Saxon Algebra</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-439" tabindex="-1">Saxon Algebra 1/2</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-440" tabindex="-1">Shormann</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-441" tabindex="-1">Shormann</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-442" tabindex="-1">Shormann Algebra 1</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-443" tabindex="-1">Shormann Algebra 2</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-444" tabindex="-1">Shormann Algebra 2 with Integrated Geometry</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-445" tabindex="-1">Singapore Math</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-446" tabindex="-1">Singapore Math</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-447" tabindex="-1">2B US Edition</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-448" tabindex="-1">5B US Edition</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-449" tabindex="-1">Teaching Textbooks</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-450" tabindex="-1">Teaching Textbooks</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subject" id="ui-id-451" tabindex="-1">Veritas Press</li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item autocomplete-subcategory" id="ui-id-452" tabindex="-1">Veritas Press</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

в консоли curriculum_tree:
[image: console.log]

Итого чего хочу добиться: чтобы для подкатегории отображалась категория при поиске по буквам - нужна любая помощь (если нужен более детальный код - готов предоставить)

Пример: [image: screen2]

Comment: Такое ощущение, что проблема где-то в другом месте. Вы в консоли смотрели отфильтрованный результат, там действительно не хватает первого элемента?

Comment: У меня такое же ощущение (там еще плагины taggle.js и autocomplete вот они скорее по своему определяют сортировку и фильтрацию)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил добавлением новой фильтрации:

```js
$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function(array, term) {
  var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
  let subjectExist = false;

  let filteredArray = $.grep(array, function(value) {
    if (value.value == 'subject') {
      subjectExist = true;
      return value;
    } else {
      return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    }
  });

  if (!subjectExist)
    return filteredArray;

  filteredArray = $.grep(filteredArray, function(value, index) {
    if (value.value == 'subject') {
      if (typeof filteredArray[index + 1] !== 'undefined') {

        if (filteredArray[index + 1].value == 'subject') {
          return false;
        } else {
          return value;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
  return filteredArray;
}
<% end %>
```